# Unable to save EKEvent as calendar is missing default organizer

Tags: swift, ekevent, ekcalendar

I am trying to save a new `EKEvent` to a new **local** calendar I create using:

```
newCalendar.source = self.eventStore.sources.filter { (source: EKSource) -> Bool in source.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.local.rawValue}.first!
```

```swift
    do {
        try self.eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit: true)
       } catch {
        throw Error.calendarNotSaved
      }
```

I return the calendar identifier and create a new EKEvent and save with:

```
newEvent.calendar = self.eventStore.calendar(withIdentifier: calendarIdentifier)!

do {
   try eventStore.save(newEvent, span:.thisEvent, commit: true)
 } catch {}
```

This fails with the error message:

> Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=54 "Calendar does not have a default organizer."

According to Apple, you can not create a new EKSource just [use an existing one to create a new calendar.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/eksource). In my case, the only local calendar does not contain any `EKOrganizer` information and is, therefore, unable to save. Any suggestions for how to move around this problem?

**Update**: Should also add that I have tried to add an organizer through EKEvent.organizer but that is a read-only property and takes its information from the EKSource you use when creating the calendar.